# What need to be done on Azure to allow our ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC to authenticate the users against Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, microsoft-identity-platform

I created a new ASP.NET Core MVC 6.0 web application >> and i define it to use Azure AD for authentication, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

then i were asked to create owned application, so i created one named "ad" as follow:-

[image]

[image]

and inside my application's appsetting i got these settings:-

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "*****",
    "TenantId": "***",
    "ClientId": "***",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```

so seems visual studio did all the work for us. now we want to deploy our application to our client office 365 tenant, so what need to be done on Azure to allow our application to connect to our client Azure AD instead of our Azure AD which was set using visual studio?

second question, now when i accessed All resources inside our Azure portal, i could not find the application named "ad" which was created inside visual studio 2022, so what is the reason?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75347054/why-my-azure-active-directory-app-created-using-visual-studio-will-not-appear-un

Answer (score 1):

`so what need to be done on Azure to allow our application to connect to our client Azure AD...`

No need to change anything in Azure Portal, when you create resource in Visual Studio, I trust you are asked to sign in first. If you signed in with the account that you used to sign in Azure portal, then the resources will appear in Azure Portal.

`i could not find the application named "ad"`

That's because you created Azure AD application which is not a service in Azure subscription. You can going to Azure portal --> choose the correct tenant if you had several tenants --> go to Azure Active Directory -->app registration --> owned applications, then you can see your `ad` application.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok thanks for the detailed reply and info, so when i want to deploy the asp.net core mvc inside the client environment i need to manually create the App registrations and change the tenant id & client id inside the appsetting.json, as i correct? or i can deploy to PRDO environment using visual studio which will create the needed app inside the client tenant for me?

Comment: for example, you created an MVC project with microsoft identity platform, you will find that the variables in appsettings.json are invalid, you need to fill them. Now you need to go to Azure portal to create Azure AD resource by yourself, then you can get the Azure ad app id, client secret, tenant id, and so on, you also need to set redirect URL. Certainly, you can also use Visual studio to create Azure AD resource for you. Then you can also get these variable values. After modifying appsetting file, you can publish your project by right click on the project and click publish.

Comment: when you try to publish your MVC project to Azure, it will also let you sign in first, then choose an Azure Web App instance, if you didn't create it in Azure portal manually, you can also create resource in Visual Studio following the options it provides to you.

Comment: here's a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core) for you which demonstrate how to integrate azure ad into asp.net core application. it contains the steps about how to create Azure ad application manually.

Comment: then this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#deploy-the-app-to-azure) shows how to publish to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully as below:***

I Registered an **`ASP.NET Core MVC 6.0`** web application:

[image]

[image]

The **`ad`** Application got created successfully like below:

[image]

And configured the Additional settings as below:

[image]

The **`appsettings.json`** file looks like below:

[image]

**Note** that: The created Azure AD Application will be reflected in the Azure Portal in *Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> All Applications*

[image]

After executing the application, I signed in and got the screen as below:

[image]

**I logged in to the Azure AD Application successfully like below:**

[image]

> Now we want to deploy our application to our client office 365 tenant, so what need to be done on Azure to allow our application to connect to our client Azure AD instead of our Azure AD which was set using visual studio?

I created an **Azure AD Application in another tenant** as below:

[image]

Now, you can change the **`appsettings.json`** file by updating the above application details like below:

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "***",
    "ClientId": "***",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```

[image]

And executing the application and I signed in with the tenant user like below:

[image]

**I logged in to the Azure AD Application successfully like below:**

[image]